# Android relativelayout with image and 2 textviews

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linears"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear"
    android:background="@color/list_background_pressed" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:text="WELCOME MONIQUE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:text="HAVE A NICE DAY!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Simple stuff, I have image in middle of layout..and 2 textviews on right and left.
However the one on left . that is welcome monique. doesnt take  the entire width to left..
how can i fix this error?

Comment: remove android:paddingLeft="10dp" and try.

Comment: if i change it fill_parent, it still doesnt help. welcome monique still on ledft of image ..but 2 lines showing...coz its not taking entire width to lefty

Comment: android:layout_alignParentStart="true" set this in textView for Welcome Monique and remove paddingLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linears"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/list_background_pressed" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/image1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:text="WELCOME MONIQUE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:text="HAVE A NICE DAY!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:id="@+id/Linear">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linears"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image1"


        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:gravity="right"  
        android:text="WELCOME MONIQUE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="11dp"
        android:gravity="left"  
        android:text="HAVE A NICE DAY!"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```